# Error MSB6006 Xamarin Forms "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022, mobile-application

I am creating a project of Mobile Application Xamarin form using Visual Studio 2022, however there's one thing a problem about my released package, when I tried to run my project on released, I am getting an error coded: MSB6006 "java.exe" exited with code 1.

I have third-party installed on my project which is the System.Data.SQLClient.
on my Debug run, the application running smoothly.

PS: this is my first time creating a mobile application

Comment: Here is the related issue about [Xamarin.Android error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1 after upgrade solution from VS2019 to VS2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/933378/xamarin-android-error-msb6006-java-exe-exited-with) you can refer to.

Comment: Found a solution about my problem, I don't know if this is an accurate reason, but it seems the framework version of .NET for xamarin.forms is not supported for released apk with SqlClient, I looked for the framework version and its only .NET 3.0, so i switched to CrossPlatform